# How to shorten the C-x C-b M-a C-s key binding bound to helm-mini Multi occur submode?

Tags: helm

I have currently bound <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd> to `helm-mini`. While running `helm-mini`, I can then type <kbd>M-a C-s</kbd> followed by typing in more characters which narrows down the candidates to those buffers that match on those characters. But, that entire <kbd>C-x C-b M-a C-s</kbd> key sequence is cumbersome.  How do I bind/rebind a shorter key sequence, e.g., <kbd>M-9</kbd>, to call whatever that longer keybinding calls?

I am aware of `helm-occur` but it only searches the current buffer, not multiple buffers, which from what I can gather is only available via the cumbersome <kbd>C-x C-b M-a C-s</kbd> sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function that does this.

```lisp
(defun helm-occur-all-buffers ()
  "Run `helm-occur' in all buffers."
  (interactive)
  (require 'helm-occur)
  (let ((buffers (cl-remove-if (lambda (buffer)
                                 ;; remove internal buffers
                                 (string= (substring (buffer-name buffer) 0 1) " "))
                               (buffer-list))))
    (helm-multi-occur-1 buffers)))
```

See also [`helm-occur-visible-buffers`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/a7b9e898296142465c0857b2d201d8d828ba7b05/helm-occur.el#L237) for similar functionality provided by Helm itself.

Comment: Thank you. I have since moved my configuration completely over to Councel and Ivy to address severe performance issues in Helm that I have yet to see in Councel and Ivy.  Thus, my incentive to test out your solution as been negated.